# string to date conversion using dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, string-to-datetime, type-coercion

```
Input String: 201801
Output String format: 01.2018
```

I tried using following but it's not working, I also looked up for string to date convesrion/coercion table in "Type Coercion Table" https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-types#type-coercion-table. I did not find something to help me with this.

```
as :date {format: "yyyyww"} as :string {format: "ww.yyyy"}
```

Appreciate if anyone has any ideas to share.

Comment: Just to confirm - the input date format is the first WEEK of 2018 (Based on the format mask you are using)? I don't think you will be able to parse that as a date, because a date needs an exact day to be valid AFAIK.

Comment: yes I agree, we can not format that as date. And yes the input date format is the first week of 2018. what is the other options we can try, any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a bit of string hackery you could just move the various parts of the input string around:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var inputDate = "201801"
---
{
    outputDate: inputDate[4..5] ++ "." ++ inputDate[0..3]
}
```

The output of that is

```
{
  "outputDate": "01.2018"
}
```

The above isn't null safe though, if there is a chance that the input date string is empty, or if it is shorter than 6 characters you will get a runtime error. You could work around that by checking the date in the DW, something like

```
outputDate: (inputDate[4..5] ++ "." ++ inputDate[0..3]) when inputDate != null and ( sizeOf inputDate ) == 6 otherwise null
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it worked smoothly. Sometimes solution lies in the simplest form. I was hellbent on trying to get it done somehow using :date format, which was not possible in this case.